# Interpretation of the wave function in newtonian spacetime

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, wavefunction, probability, quantum-interpretations

A Newtonian spacetime is a quintuple $(M, \mathcal{O}, \mathcal{A}, \nabla, t)$ where $(M, \mathcal{O}, \mathcal{A}, \nabla)$ is a 4 dimensional differentiable manifold with a torsion free connection, and $t$$\in C^{\infty}(M)$ is such that $dt\neq 0$ and $\nabla dt=0$.

Since time $t$ is absolute  there  exist 3 dimensional plane of simultaneity.
Now my question is, what is the interpretation of probability density $|\psi(x)|^2$ ?

Is it the probability that the  particle is  at position $x$ in relation to an observer or, is it  the  probability that the particle is at a point $x$ in the plane of simultaneity defined at time $t$?

Comment: of finding the particle, but by whom? The observer. However, the observer could just be the environment

Comment: i am not understanding what  you mean

Comment: I do not understand why someone wants to close this question. Maybe it is not written into an explicit way, but it deals  with a physically relevant and subtle issue regarding the nature of the non-relativistic quantum wavefunction: whether or not it is represented by a classical scalar field. The answer is negative for $\psi$ but positive for the associated probabiliy distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even restricting to the class of observers where the connection coefficients vanish (inertial observers), the function $\psi$ depends on the observer, since the action of Galileian group is not trivial on $\psi$: it cannot be considered a scalar field over the 3-surfaces at constant absolute time in view of the appearance  of a phase depending on $x$ and $t$ (and on the element of the group). Conversely, its squared absolute value you consider (the probability)  is independent from the observer.
Therefore $x$ can be viewed as a point in the absolute space at time $t$ if dealing with $|\psi(t, x)|^2$, since this object is a scalar field over that manifold (at fixed time) as the phase disappears when computing the absolute value, whereas this intepretation is impossible when directly dealing with $\psi(t,x)$, because every chart associated to every different observer assigns a different  value even if $x$ defines the same point in the absolute space.

Comment: Say we are in 2 dimension 1 for spatial and 1 for time. and we have  $X \phi=x \phi$. what am trying to understand if this $x$ is a point in the manifold or the position of the particle in relation to the observer

Comment: In your book  (A5 (b)) you defined  like this . why can we not defined independently  of an  observer ?

Comment: Because when changing the observer you sould also change the value of $\psi$ at the same point of absolute space, since a phase appears in front of $\psi$.

Comment: What I am saying is just that $\psi$ cannot be assumed to be a scalar field.

Comment: However, yes when writing $\psi(x)$,   $x$ is referred to the observer, it is a point in the coordinate system of a given observer and not a point in the common manifold shared by the observers.